# how to store data in a txt (using jsp)

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jsp

I've been trying to store some data in a txt file using the code below

```
<%
FileWriter file = null;
String text = request.getParameter("texto");
try{
    String path = application.getRealPath("/") + "prueba.txt";
    file = new FileWriter(path);
    file.write(text);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

but when i try to open this file, the file is empty, how can i fix that? is there another better way to write a file in jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You should also call the flush method of the FileWriter class (or close method if you won't be writing again). Example:

```
<%
FileWriter writer = null;
String text = request.getParameter("texto");
try{
    String path = application.getRealPath("/") + "prueba.txt";
    writer = new FileWriter(path);
    writer.write(text);
    writer.flush();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this situation is manually close the FW by calling the close() method. this will save the buffered content to the disk.

Also you can try calling the flush method of the FileWriter(but this is not necessary if your calling close). This is because FileWriter have a default bufer size of 1024 chars(check java.io.Writer).When your write the content to FW, first it move the content to the buffer and whenever it exceed the 1024 limit or when you close the FW, it will save the bufer content to the disk. So by manually calling the flush() method you can save the buffered content to the disk without waiting for the close() or exceed the 1024 limit.

```
    FileWriter file = null;
    String text = request.getParameter("texto");
    try{
        String path = application.getRealPath("/") + "prueba.txt";
        file = new FileWriter(path);
        file.write(text);

        //This is not necessary if you closing the FW
        file.flush(); 

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    

    }finally {

        try {

            if (file != null)
                file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```